Where is the following sanskrit verse found?
"पितृव्यां मातुलं चैव यः कामयेत भार्यया | स वध्यः पापकरो नात्र कार्या विचार्यते"
"He who lusts after his father's sister or mother's sister is a sinner and shall be killed, no consideration is necessary."
Please dont use ai tool it shows same verse in multiple smritis and puranas.

Is this close enough? "The man who makes his daughter, his sister or his sister-in-law an object of lust, is punishable by death; this is the law!"
